# How pass selected spinner value to different url

Tags: php, android, spinner

I have two spinners "Route" and "Station" and the second spinner dependent on the first one, so I developed the code and it is working but now I need to get the value of selected spinner of the second one (Station) and send it to another url server (php) //http://localhost/Android/v1/test1.php
but I didn't find a solution.

I tried to do what I have done with routeSpinner but it doesn't work I didn't get the selected value.

```
 spinnerStation = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerStation);
 spinnerRoute = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerRoute);
 stationList = new ArrayList<Station>();

 spinnerRoute.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Refresh Spinner
            stationList.clear();
            new GetStationFromServer().execute();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    private class GetStationFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this); 
        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data");
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        routeName = spinnerRoute.getSelectedItem().toString();



        Handler jsonParser = new Handler();


        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall("http://192.168.1.2/   Android/v1/get_station.php?route="+routeName, Handler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);



        if (json != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray station = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("station");

                    for (int i = 0; i < station.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject modObj =(JSONObject)station.get(i);
                        Station mod = new Station  (    modObj.getString("station"));
                        stationList.add(mod);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        populateSpinnerStation();
    }
}

private void populateSpinnerStation() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < stationList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(stationList.get(i).getStation());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerStation.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}
```

I expect to pass the selected spinner of station like what I did with route spinner to the server and continue my application but it show an error "Undefined index"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicity passing the string to the AsyncTask, instead of asking the Async task to find the selected string?

Like this in route spinner listener:

```
spinnerRoute.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Refresh Spinner
        stationList.clear();
        routeName = spinnerRoute.getSelectedItem().toString();
        new GetStationFromServer().execute(routeName);
    }
```

And changing Async Task to:

```
  private class GetStationFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {   
    String s = params[0];
    Handler jsonParser = new Handler();
    String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall("http://192.168.1.2/  
    Android/v1/get_station.php?route="+s, Handler.GET);
}
```

Comment: yes but it still dosen't work ... in php file I put $station=$_GET['station']; no ?